# How can I get all results with count, where in, group by in mysql and myBatis?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, mybatis

I'd like to know how to get all results including count value is 0 in SQL mapper.

I've sent ajax request in my javascript.

```
var programGoals = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
```

(The data's count value is A=3, B=2, C=1, D=0. And I'd like to get all results including D's 0)

And it's the myBatis Mapper file. (using mysql)

```
   <select id="countCardsWithProgramGoal" resultType="java.util.HashMap" 
          parameterType="java.util.HashMap">
       select pgoal, count(*) as count
       from PROG
       where pgoal in
        <foreach collection="programGoals_list" item="item" index="index" 
            separator="," open="(" close=")">
            #{item}
        </foreach>
       group by pgoal;
</select>
```

It returns only A, B, C results excluding D which count result is 0.
How can I get all values?
Thanks in advance. cheers.

Comment: You want to count something that doesn't exists (rows with pgoal = 'D') and that is difficult with sql. Might be easier to solve this in the frontend instead.

Answer (score 0):

As it was stated it is probably easier to do that out of database but if you do want to do that in DB you can:

1. use `union all` to construct a result set from the list of passed goals and then
2. left join to it and then
3. group like you are doing now

The query will be like this:

```
<select id="countCardsWithProgramGoal" resultType="java.util.HashMap" 
      parameterType="java.util.HashMap">
   select g.pgoal, count(*) as count
   from (
     SELECT 
     <foreach collection="programGoals_list" item="item" index="index" 
        separator=" UNION ALL SELECT " >
        #{item} pgoal
    </foreach>
      ) as g
      left join PROG p on p.pgoal = g.pgoal
   group by pgoal;
</select>
```